# Convert iso8601 date to basic date format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, iso

I'm trying to convert a ISO8601 date format (example: `2010-06-13T01:45:03Z`) to a basic, simple format such as this: `"DD-MM-YYYY"`. On top of this, I want to be able to convert the ISO8601 date to the difference between the ISO date and the current date, in days. E.g. With the input of an ISO of a date 1 year ago, return 365 days.  I've tried a couple libraries to help with this but im struggling to do it.

Comment: What research have you done? If you did some, you'd notice that this question has been answered many times before.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/215552 for the date difference. As already mentioned, please do some research. I searched for your title question and got "About 322,000 results"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library http://momentjs.com  And as an exercise read the manual and find out how you can do it by yourself ;)

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.

Comment: That is correct. My mistake.